# Why does changing the order of these instructions significantly affect performance?

Tags: c++, c, optimization

For an assignment at school, I'm performing an intensive operation on a very large array of numbers. While benchmarking a single-threaded version operating on the whole array and comparing my results to my classmate's, I noticed some strange behavior.

The function is as follows:

```
int compute (char a[], int start, int end) {
    int sum = 0;
    int min = a[start];
    int max = a[start];

    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        if (a[i] > max) max = a[i];
        if (a[i] < min) min = a[i];

        int cube = a[i] * a[i] * a[i];
        sum += cube;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

But my classmate's program is consistently running faster, often much faster. His code is identical, except for the order of the instructions in the loop body:

```
for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
    int cube = a[i] * a[i] * a[i];
    sum += cube;

    if (a[i] > max) max = a[i];
    if (a[i] < min) min = a[i];
}
```

Here's the output comparing the runtime of each version with an input array of size 1,000,000,000 (initialized with random signed bytes):

```
Min/max first:
sum = 5445493143089, min = -128, max = 127
Completed in 1.050268 sec

Product-sum first:
sum = 5445493143089, min = -128, max = 127
Completed in 1.010639 sec
```

We have inspected the generated assembly for both versions and noticed the same instructions present, simply ordered differently. To my knowledge, this shouldn't have as significant an effect as it does, but I could be wrong. (We also noticed that the registers used differed greatly, but this I *especially* doubt should have an effect.)

We encounter this behavior when compiling for both C (`-std=c11`) and C++ (`-std=c++11`).

**Why is the order of those lines heavily affecting the behavior of the sequential program?** We are also benchmarking a parallel version of the operation, and in contrast, its behavior is almost unchanged. I looked into memory reordering as a possible culprit, but that doesn't appear to be the problem since the parallel version is virtually unaffected (and there's no overlap in the partitions anyway).

**[Intensive back-to-back tests](http://rextester.com/CHQU74554)** demonstrating the behavior. Product-sum is always faster than min/max, even in alternation and allowing for caching.

Comment: He could be getting slightly better I-cache or D-cache performance with the instruction reordering.

Comment: Please show the generated assembly for both cases.

Comment: Just making sure - this is of course compiled with -O3 or similar, right?

Comment: Yes, `-O3` was used.

Comment: Can you give a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @black not sure how to make this more minimal than it is. =/

Comment: @Purag The missing part isn't the minimal, but rather the complete part.  Take an online compiler, and write up a test harness around the above.  The test harness should be another 20-40 lines of code.  Demonstrate that the error happens in the online version.  Once done, someone can take your code and pay with the same apples, instead of having to recreate it from a description, end up with a watermelon, and get different results than you do.  You are the best person to create a minimal, complete example, and it is your problem, so you should be the one who does the work!

Comment: Could you post the assembler output (for x86 fx)? Which processor did you use? Did you optimize for the same processor that you used? As far as I can see the compiler should be allowed to reorder the operations in the loop and cosequently choose the fastest (or am I wrong here?), the output could be the same (the fastest) if the compiler were smart enough.

Comment: I have the opposite results both at `IdeOne` and at my computer with `-O3` flag - http://ideone.com/1PqJIf

Comment: I had this result on x86 and SPARC architectures.

Comment: Might be worth breaking out AMD CodeXL or Intel VTune to profile and see where the slow down really is happening.

Comment: Sad, standard algorithm is not the fastest version :( [Demo](http://ideone.com/Ue7Veg)

Comment: I'll put my demo up later today! Need a site that lets me compile with `O3`.

Comment: Having quickly scanned the assembly, it looks like the second version uses one additional register...

Comment: @Purag: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ let you set compiler flags.

Comment: Can you show us the full test code? I'm unable to reproduce these results locally. I get identical timings on GCC4.8 -O3.

Comment: Also, what are the specs of the machine? Sandy Bridge? Haswell? And how many cores?

Comment: @Purag You can also use http://gcc.godbolt.org/ and it will even show you the generated assembly.

Comment: @Jarod42 Just wanted to let you know about http://gcc.godbolt.org/.  mostly the same as coliru but you also get the assembly.

Comment: All: [Here's my demo](http://rextester.com/KNQ44712). The behavior is as I reported in the question; the version with the min/max check first is consistently faster, and by quite a bit in some cases.

Comment: So I'm going to clarify the question; I tagged it C++ naively because of the multithreading part, which is actually not essential to the question.

Comment: Note: `long long` is pointless in `long long square = a[i] * a[i];` as the product is calculated _before_ conversion to `long long`.  If `long long` is needed, then `long long square = 1LL*a[i] * a[i];`.  Else make code faster with `int square = a[i] * a[i];`.  Function before performance.

Comment: @chux you're right; that's just remnant from when I wrote this code which was actually a while ago (I just got around to posting the question here). At the time I was just starting to learn C.

Comment: @Purag Do you get consistent results if the "Square sum first:" first and then "Min/max first:" second?.  If the there is a reversal, the issue is  all the un-cached data on the first pass takes more time.  Try testing A, B tests in this order `ABBA`.

Comment: @chux Interesting question, hadn't tried it before. [It turns out that the behavior is the same](http://rextester.com/BOXC89974). Square sum is consistently faster.

Comment: 2-3% difference makes this a lot less interesting than your original numbers (which I cannot reproduce). Seeing that GCC generates a crazy amount of vector code under O3, 2-3% is well within the normal compiler variability. So I doubt there are any interesting hardware effects involved.

Comment: @Mysticial The problem is the online execution keeps `SIGKILL`ing with bigger numbers. The effect is much more obvious with larger numbers.

Comment: @Purag If you can tell us more about your original environment it would be great. What processors? How many cores? The numbers that you are showing with the online compilers aren't statistically interesting and are similar to what everyone else is getting locally. Since nobody is able to reproduce your original results, do you have specialized hardware?

Comment: @Mysticial I'm running tests on my school servers. There are two; one is a Solaris machine running on the Sun SPARC architecture; it has 8 cores and 64 virtual processors. The other is a Red Hat machine running on x86; it has 4 cores (not sure about virtual processors).

Comment: When I compile with `-std=c++11` on the x86 machine, I get the same result on both machines; square sum is faster. However, without that flag, min/max is always faster on x86. Either way, ordering the instructions has a very noticeable effect; I'm just interested in understanding why that's the case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we put explicit jumps into the code, you can see that the one with the conditionals at the end can avoid one jump most of the time. This is similar to the code that will actually be generated by the compiler.

First form, min/max first:

```
    int i = lo;
    goto start;
loop:
    i++;
start:
    if (!(i < hi)) goto end;
    if (!(a[i] > ret.max)) goto label1;
    ret.max = a[i];
label1:
    if (!(a[i] < ret.min)) goto label2;
    ret.min = a[i];
label2:

    long long square = a[i] * a[i];
    ret.sum += square;
    goto loop;
end:
```

Second form, min/max last:

```
    int i = lo;
    goto start;
loop:
    i++;
start:
    if (!(i < hi)) goto end;
    long long square = a[i] * a[i];
    ret.sum += square;

    if (!(a[i] > ret.max)) goto label1;
    ret.max = a[i];
label1:
    if (!(a[i] < ret.min)) goto loop;
    ret.min = a[i];
    goto loop;
end:
```

Comment: Okay, I see. So with the conditionals at the end, we're consolidating breaking out of the second `if` and returning to the start of the loop. Whereas in the first version, we need to jump past both conditionals no matter what. Clever!

Comment: I think I'll accept this, but a follow-up: should the effect of this be as significant as sometimes half a second of difference in run time?

Comment: @Purag a half second could just be from the way you're measuring the elapsed time, or from other activity on your system interfering with the test. The only time you gave showed a difference of .04 seconds, which is well explained by the difference shown here.

Comment: Those were the results from the online compiler. On my local machine, I was getting differences up to 1 second and more. It's a Solaris machine running on the SPARC architecture, 8 cores. Not sure what could cause that much of a difference.

Answer (score 4):

It could be as simple as the processor jump prediction works better with the conditional jumps at the bottom of the loop...

Comment: Is this a guess, or did you try it?

Comment: @TonyTheLion It is fine to post possible solution (i.e guesses) as answers. Of course, as far as these are meaningful.

Comment: Let's call it an educated guess... I've done detailed clock timing analysis of loops like this before.